# SFINAE does not work as expected

Tags: c++, sfinae, partial-specialization

I am reading [this article](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/03/named-optional-template-parameters-compile-time.html) and find this piece of code using `SFINAE` very interesting:

```
template<typename D, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct get_value_int<D, T2, Args...> {
    template<typename D2, typename T22, typename Enable = void>
    struct impl
        : std::integral_constant<int, get_value_int<D, Args...>::value> {};

    template<typename D2, typename T22>
    struct impl <D2, T22, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename D2::type_id, typename T22::type_id>::value>>
        : std::integral_constant<int, T22::value> {};

    static constexpr const int value = impl<D, T2>::value;
};
```

As I understand, if the template class `std::enable_if_t` could not be instaniated, the first version of `impl` would be.

However, when I try to write a simpler piece of code, which I think pretty much the same as the one above, it gets compile errors. Do I misunderstand something here?

```
 template<typename T,typename N = void>
 class A
 {

 };

 template <typename T>
 class A<T, typename enable_if<false>::type>
 {

 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFINAE occurs in immediate context, here your condition doesn't depend of `T` so it is a hard failure, your code should be something like:

```
template <typename T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<condition<T>::value>::type>
{
};
```

Comment: Your solution works. However, when I copy the code that does not compile in my question from Sublime Text 3 to VS 2015, it works and I have no idea why.

Comment: @Rickie: `msvc` is not standard-compliant for some stuff with template (and mainly with non-dependency). I think it would give you the error once you instantiate `A<T>`.